# How to disable zoom in a ChartViewer

Tags: javafx, jfreechart-fx

I'm working with [jfreechart-fx](/questions/tagged/jfreechart-fx). I created a scroll panel and I have a [`ChartViewer`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart-fx/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/fx/ChartViewer.java) (not a ChartPanel) inside of it. Inside the chart, I plot data using a `CombinedDomainXYPlot`. I add some data to the combined plot at runtime:

```
XYPlot subplot;

for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    dataset = .....
    subplot = new XYPlot(dataset, null, rangeAxis1, renderer);
    myCombinedPlot.add(subplot)
}

String panel_title = "bla bla";
myChartViewer.setChart(new JFreeChart(panel_title, JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, myCombinedPlot, false));
```

Now, when I drag and drop on my graph, I see that the default operation of mouse is the *zoom* on the signal. **How do I disable this default function?** I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
myChartViewer.getCanvas().setRangeZoomable(false);
myChartViewer.getCanvas().setDomainZoomable(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is controlled by an instance of `ZoomHandlerFX` installed by the [`ChartViewer`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart-fx/blob/8ac05178c9b62cd5d7f093413688b81c918d6668/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/fx/ChartViewer.java#L97) constructor. To eliminate zooming entirely, simply remove the handler.

```
ChartViewer chartViewer = new ChartViewer(chart);
ChartCanvas canvas = chartViewer.getCanvas();
canvas.removeMouseHandler(canvas.getMouseHandler("zoom"));
```

If you later need to restore the handler, invoke `addMouseHandler()` like [this](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart-fx/blob/8ac05178c9b62cd5d7f093413688b81c918d6668/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/fx/ChartViewer.java#L105):

```
canvas.addMouseHandler(new ZoomHandlerFX("zoom", chartViewer));
```